# Hyper-V R2: Need help with disk structure

Tags: raid, virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, virtualization

I'm going to use the free (non gui) version of Hyper-V R2.

In my new server I have 8 disks in total (for Hyper-V R2 installation and virtual machine).

Atm I'm going to run a single virtual machine, with following tasks:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 x64
- File/Print
- SQL Server

My question is ... with my 8 disks in the server, which disks should contain wich data? Should I install "Hyper-V R2" and VM's drive c on same physical disks? Should I use raid 1 or 5?

With the above tasks, how would you structure the disks?

Hope you know what I mean (I'm not english, so it's difficult to explain).

Thanks!!!

Mojo

Comment: Going to be a complex answer could you post cpu(S), network cards, and what storage controller you are using by chance?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have much virtualization experience.  The first thing I would suggest is to use one VM for each of your workloads.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much about your machine's configuration, I would suggest that you have one disk for booting Hyper-V and put the rest in a RAID set that makes the most of your available I/O bandwidth.

Whether you go for RAID5/6 or something a little faster should depend on your backup strategy.  If you're well backed up all the time, you might forgo the redundancy in the name of raw speed.

Then put all the VM state on the RAID set.